# showing warning in bottom panel in Guidewire

Tags: user-interface, guidewire

I am working on customization of Guidewire's *ClaimCenter*, and in certain situation I want to show warning in bottom panel which is usually displayed by common `rejectField()` method.
Can I somehow display this same panel without using `rejectField()` method ?
If not, may I somehow implement such method on Payment entity ?
(Keep in mind that I am working on customization, and I do not have access to most of Guidewire's source code.)

Answer (score 0):

You will generally call `rejectField` on a validation rule. That will bring up a popup tab with a warning. You cannot get the same type of experience but you can bring in warnings on a yellow bar using the `Alert Bar` element on the pcf. You can put in conditions as needed for the alter bar to be displayed.